# Facing Compare Issue in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I am trying to compare the response time to two releases of the product. But when I trying to create the comparison table, I am facing issue. In the below **picture 1** you can see that, both release filter is applied and is giving value when I have selected the same release but when I change the release version, I am not able to see the data, which you can see in **picture 2**.

Simply when we select the same value in the slicer it is giving value else not.

In below,

**new_release_id** is the field in release table i.e **release_id** which is converted into slicer

**old_release_id** is the new column with name **Rel_Column** which duplicates the value of **release_id** of the release table.

I made two fields with the same value so that I can use the **SELECTEDVALUE** feature in the DAX uniquely.

In the table comparision,

**sample_name** is the field in response_time table

**NewReleaseAverage** is the calculated field in the response_time table and the DAX is -

**NewReleaseAverage =
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE('public response_time'[average]),
'public response_time'[release_id] = SELECTEDVALUE('public release'[release_id])
)**

Similarly, **OldReleaseAverage** is the calculated field in the response_time table and the DAX is -

**OldReleaseAverage =
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE('public response_time'[average]),
'public response_time'[release_id] = SELECTEDVALUE('public release'[Rel_Column])
)**

Picture 1
[image: Picture one]

Picture 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The result could be blank because there are no rows that satisfy both filter conditions.

To mitigate, you can either create a new table for the "old release" slicer (with the same data) or can try using ALL() function to clear filters, something like:

```
OldReleaseAverage = CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('public response_time'[average]),
    ALL('public release'),
    'public response_time'[release_id] = SELECTEDVALUE('public release'[Rel_Column])
)
```